# How to define the symbol by command?

Tags: math-mode, macros

There is a notation:

```
\mathbf{P}^{m}_{b}(n)
```

How can it be defined using `\newcommand` ?

PS The variables m, b, n should be as arguments

Comment: `\newcommand*\mysymbol{\mathbf{P}^{m}_{b}(n)}` and then in the document use `\mysymbol` in math mode.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I want to be able to edit the vaieables, how could I do it ?

Comment: In mathematical practice, you will want these various arguments to be optional, so you really want to use xparse.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay, it is true, but need to be very careful using xparse package, since the not all online tex processors are able to use new version of xparse, for example, in case of submission to arXiv.org, you have to proceed xparse of TeX-Live 2016, i.e avoid to use the actual syntax of xparse, but proceed the old one

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In LaTeX you can define a new macro with `\newcommand`. `\newcommand` can have an optional star, which determines whether arguments of the newly created macro can contain a `\par` (or two consecutive newlines) or not. The next is the name of the new macro. After that are two optional arguments, the first specifying the number of arguments and the second if used defines a default for an optional argument, which is always the first argument. And after that follows the definition of the macro.

```latex
\newcommand*\mycmd{my replacement}
```

defines a new macro called `\mycmd` that is replaced by `my replacement` when expanded.

```latex
\newcommand\mycmd[1]{my replacement with the argument ``#1''}
```

defines a new macro that takes one argument. Correct usage would be something like `\mycmd{mandatory}`.

```latex
\newcommand\mycmd[2][default]{optional argument: ``#1''; mandatory argument: ``#2''}
```

defines a new macro with two arguments, the first being optional, the second mandatory. Correct usage would be something like `\mycmd[optional]{mandatory}` or `\mycmd{mandatory}`.

---

So in your case, if nothing should change, you could use

```latex
\newcommand*\mysymbol{\mathbf{P}^{m}_{b}(n)}
```

if you want the indices to be flexible, you can use

```latex
\newcommand\mynotation[2]{\mathbf{P}^{#1}_{#2}(n)}
```

and then you could use `\mynotation{m}{b}` in the document.

If also the `P` should be changeable, you can use something like

```latex
\newcommand\mynotation[3][P]{\mathbf{#1}^{#2}_{#3}(n)}
```

Then you could use `\mynotation[P]{m}{b}` or `\mynotation{m}{b}`.

If you even want the `(n)` to be variable, you can add another argument

```latex
\newcommand\mynotation[4][P]{\mathbf{#1}^{#2}_{#3}(#4)}
```

Then `\mynotation[P]{m}{b}{n}` or `\mynotation{m}{b}{n}` could be used.

---

To get a more powerful interface to define macros, you could use [`xparse`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xparse), with it you could define your macro with

```latex
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand \mynotation { O{P} E{^_}{mb} D(){n} }{\mathbf{#1}^{#2}_{#3}(#4)}
```

Then you could use

- `\mynotation` and it would expand to `\mathbf{P}^{m}_{b}(n)`
- `\mynotation[B]` and it would expand to `\mathbf{B}^{m}_{b}(n)`
- `\mynotation^{e}` and it would expand to `\mathbf{P}^{e}_{b}(n)`
- `\mynotation_{d}` and it would expand to `\mathbf{P}^{m}_{d}(n)`
- `\mynotation(x)` and it would expand to `\mathbf{P}^{m}_{b}(x)`
- `\mynotation[B]^{e}_{d}(x)` and it would expand to `\mathbf{B}^{e}_{d}(x)`, which would be the same as `\mynotation[B]_{d}^{e}(x)`.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what required

Comment: @PetroKolosov take a look at the `xparse` example.

Comment: Ah, I dont even have this package installed on my tex editor :( 
[And I don't know how to install it actually :)]

Comment: @PetroKolosov which LaTeX distribution and which version of it do you use? `xparse` is a pretty standard package that is used by many other packages. If your installation isn't ancient, `xparse` should be contained in it.

Comment: I use WinEdt 8.1 and MikTeX 2.9 on board, seems that long time i've not updated it

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you again, but can you translate your xparse expressions in terms of loder version on xparse package (<2016 such that arxiv supports it)

Comment: @PetroKolosov Sorry, but I'm afraid this wasn't part of `xparse` in 2016.

Answer (score 3):

Following the usual notations for projective space, I use:

[image: projective space notations]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\Proj{e^e_d()}{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{\mathbb{P}}{\mathbb{P}_{\!#2}}}%
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}{\mathbb{P}^{#1}}{\mathbb{P}^{#1}_{\!#2}}}%
    \IfValueTF{#3}{\!\left(#3\right)}{}%
}%
\begin{document}
\(\Proj^n, \Proj_k, \Proj^n_k, \Proj(V), \Proj^n(k)\)
\end{document}
```

Comment: good suggestion, I'd giva an upvote, but acnnot [too low score] :)